# Error : the user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I complete my database in SQL Server 2008, and then I get to connect database in Visual Studio 2015, I set user instance true but my problem no dissolve.
[image]

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2008 are you using? I believe User Instances are only Supported by the Express editions. It's also possible that User Instances are currently not enabled. Have a look here to see how to enable that feature: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31185f91-be4c-4cf9-b8d9-9583a02aa894/error-the-user-instance-login-flag-is-not-supported-on-this-version-of-sql-server?forum=lightswitchgeneral

Comment: Try modifying your connection string after having manually

Comment: I use enterprise edition.

Comment: `User Instance` is supported ***only*** in the **Express** edition of SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error description says that UserInstance feature  is not supported (it is supported by Express editions only I believe), so why not to disable it? If you`re doing it from code, add to the connection line "User Instance=True;"

Answer (score -1):

1. add new ADO.net entity data model;
2. in the wizard: select 'EF designer from database';
3. select new connection button;
4. change data source from 'microsoft sql server' to 'microsoft sql server database file';
5. browse your database.